# Commenting on Stack Exchange Blog should use Stack Exchange credentials

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, user-card, network-profile

When commenting on one of the community blogs, or even the Stack Exchange blog, users are required to provide onetime credentials. It would be nice to be able to use my Stack Exchange credentials when commenting.

Further comments could then display Stack Exchange User Cards instead of just a gravatar. Not sure how many non-community members comment on the various blogs but anonymous posting could also be allowed if desired.

Comment: I thought this was a dupe but I can't find it, so +1. Maybe it was a comment *on* a blog post that I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While this was a pain in the past, a few things have happened that have made this more reasonable to do:

- the Stack Exchange API v2.0 added authentication
- the WordPress hooks that enable a plugin to meddle in the authentication process have become much more documented, and involve wayyyyyyy less guesswork and pain in figuring out.

We've enabled this on the SE 2.0 blogs, and it will be enabled on the Super User and Server Fault blogs soon.  After making sure it is rock solid on Blog Overflow, we'll look at putting it on the main Stack Exchange company blog at https://blog.stackoverflow.com.

[More details can be found in this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140597/stack-exchange-blogs-authentication-now-with-80-less-suck)

Comment: awesome! that'll be really nice for all the blogs.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from time and effort, the only reason to keep them separate is that when the sites go down, you don't want the blogs depending on stackauth and elsewhere for downtime info.

Of course, that can be overcome with more time and effort.

It certainly doesn't have a unified "feel" as it stands, though.

Comment: Authentication against the API with a fallback to the default comment posting form would probably not be a huge undertaking, hmm...