# Stack Exchange Blogs Authentication, now with 80% less suck!

Tags: discussion, blog-overflow

> **It appears that this post hasn't been entirely clear on how brand new blog users register. Check [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140812/has-the-new-blogoverflow-login-changed-the-way-we-create-blog-accounts/146567#146567) for a quick explanation on the process. Otherwise, read below for the announcement.**

You may have heard that [a portion of our Wordpress Blogs were compromised on July 2nd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138576/stack-exchange-blogs-compromised-and-passwords-reset). We took down the blogs immediately on detection, identified the problem, cleared it, and gave people instructions to reset their password.

We also made the decision to change the security on our blogs - by integrating it with the Stack Exchange API. Thanks to long hard work from neophyte SE developer [Rebecca Chernoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181481/rebecca-chernoff), coupled with Kevin Montrose’s efforts on [the Stack Exchange API v2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-public-beta/) and our crack sysadmin team, rather than needing some tertiary Wordpress login it is now possible to log in to our blogs with the same credentials you use to access our network!

It's simple. When a normal contributor to a blog goes to log in to the blog, instead of being presented with a standard Wordpress login, they'll be prompted to login via OpenID instead:

[image: Image of the login route for the blogs]

Anonymous commenting remains allowed, but users who don't post on the blog but still want to comment are also able to log in to the blog, with a very familiar UI:

[image: Image of a sample comment form on the Bicycles Blog]

Now, user accounts on the blog will also be linked to the corresponding user on the site - the avatar will be automatically drawn, and the username will link to the user's site account. In the event a user comments but doesn't have an account specifically on that site, we draw from the user's main stackexchange.com account.

[image: Image of a user's comment on the Bicycles Blog]

With this implemented, no longer will we need to store sensitive email and password data on our blogs. The same security we use to keep your data safe on the rest of the network extends to protect your identity on the blogs. Furthermore, by reducing the complexity of having an account to "Logging in with your Stack Exchange Network credentials", we hope to improve participation network wide, both for commenters and for contributors alike.

---

**Note:** This is currently enabled for all Stack Exchange blogs *except* for Server Fault, Super User, and Stack Overflow (the first two are using a separate theme that will need to be converted first, and the latter is not part of Blog Overflow).

---

If you have *any* trouble with the new authentication, please ping @RebeccaChernoff or @GraceNote in the [Stack Exchange Community Blog Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs).

Comment: Let's change out the word "neophyte" with "evil" :)

Comment: Nice, that's one step in the right direction there!

Comment: @animuson: not saying that's accurate, but... She *may* have written this title and silently attributed it to Grace Note...

Comment: So if I log in my gravatar will turn into Derpy? Because that's what I got out of this post.

Comment: @Ben: yes, that was the primary design goal when we started this.

Comment: @Shog9 excellent, logging in via Stack Exchange immediately

Comment: Awesome - the new login works quite well.

Comment: Looks like a step [in the right direction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110998/130064)? :)