# Has the new blogoverflow login changed the way we create blog accounts?

Tags: support, blog

Until now, anybody who wanted a contributor account on our blog had to mail me, and I created a new user on the WordPress instance.

Now [Stack Exchange Blogs Authentication, now with 80% less suck!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140597/stack-exchange-blogs-authentication-now-with-80-less-suck) was implemented, I don't know what this change means.

I assume (but I am not entirely sure) that I still have to create new user accounts on Wordpress (or is every StackExchange account now automatically a blogoverflow account?). If my assumption is correct, are there some constraints to make sure that they can log in with their StackExchange account? For example, must the WP account be connected to the same e-mail address as the StackExchange account?

Comment: It would be awesome if we could have people create wordpress accounts without emails. I *hate* requesting emails, it's extremely difficult to do on a public site with proper respect to privacy

Comment: @BenBrocka are you saying that you have no way for them giving you the e-mail without it being visible to others, or that you find the whole idea of them giving you an email incompatible with good privacy practice?

Comment: Objection; leading the witness! But yeah, option 2. I make a dummy email account I give out sparingly for people to email me about wordpress logins, so I do have a way, it's just awkward and annoying (and still at a risk of spam for me)

Comment: Interesting. We made a blog admins e-mail account too, but we see this as an advantage, not disadvantage. Our contributors know that this is the best place to reach us for anything blog-related, and we use it for more than just account creation. We made it a gmail address, and we haven't had spam there yet (while my primary e-mail address receives spam now and then).

Comment: We're not organized enough yet to have an "admin email", it's just something I made so we could actually add users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User creation is actually done by the user, actually, not the job of the blog admins. In fact, outside of adding permissions to a contributor, the admin doesn't even have to step in.

This was originally added to the announcement post near the end, but I guess it was tucked enough, so I've moved it here as an answer.

---

For those who just want to poke around commenting, it's exactly the same process described in the announcement you linked - you go to the login page of the corresponding blog (this will be at the `/wp-admin` extension on that blog, so for example `http://diy.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin/` would be the login page for the [Home Improvement Blog](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/)). Specify your SE credentials and you're done and set!

For those who wish to be contributors, they'll do the exact same thing. Afterwards, any blog admin can go into the admin panel for the blog, and will just have to change the permissions for the user from "Subscriber" to whatever the desired permission is. No hassle or needing to mess around with confirmation emails or anything - it's just a single setting that's instant to switch.

Comment: Why is the way to create an account practically kept secret? There's a “contribute” link which goes to a description of what kind of content is sought, but I can't see a link to how to create an account or log in anywhere.

Comment: @Gilles Not meant to be a secret. Lack of execution in implementation is the reason it isn't as obvious as it should be. The new process was primarily done to adapt as accordance to the existing UI - in which contributor creation was already somewhat behind-the-scenes. We didn't change any of that UI so that portion remained hidden, somewhat for worse now. That'd be why I did the first revision to my announcement for this - it wasn't clear and there needs to be an explanation of it.